# How to solve a system of non linear equations of the form $2ax-2x(ax^2+by^2) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

Solve this system for $x,y$: 
$$2ax-2x(ax^2+by^2) = 0\tag{1}$$
$$2by-2y(ax^2+by^2) = 0\tag{2}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants such that $a>b>0$.

I re-arranged (1) to $x = \sqrt{\frac{a-by^2}{a}}$ and tried substituting it into (2)  but I did not know where to go from there. I'm looking for real solutions.

Comment: I re-arranged eq. 1 to $x = \sqrt{\frac{a-by^2}{a}}$
and tried substituting it into eq. 2 but i did not know where to go from there

Comment: Are you looking for real or integer solutions?  Generically, in the complex field you will get four solutions.  They look to be a mess.  You can solve one equation for $x$ in terms of $y$ and get a quartic, solve the quartic (a *big* mess) and back substitute.

Comment: im looking for real solutions

Answer (score 3):

$2ax-2x(ax^2+by^2) = 2x(a-ax^2-by^2)=0 \implies x=0 $ or $ a(1-x^2)=by^2$
$2by-2y(ax^2+by^2) = 2y(a-ax^2-by^2)=0 \implies y=0 $ or $ b(1-y^2)=ax^2$

Then you can try this 4 cases.

Answer (score 2):

If $x = 0$, the first equation is ok, and:

$$
2by-2y(ax^2+by^2) = 0 \\
2by-2y(by^2) = 0 \\
by-by^3 = 0 \\
y-y^3 = 0 \\
y(1-y^2) = 0
$$

Thus, either $y=0$ or $y=1$ or $y=-1$. Here we have three solutions.

If $x \ne 0$:
$$
2ax-2x(ax^2+by^2) = 0 \\
ax = x(ax^2+by^2) \\
a = ax^2+by^2
$$

Replacing in the second equation, we have:
$$
2by-2y(ax^2+by^2) = 0 \\
by - y(ax^2+by^2) = 0\\
by - ya = 0 \\
y(b-a) = 0
$$

As $a > b$, the only solution is $y=0$. So:
$$
a = ax^2+by^2 \\
a = ax^2 \\
1 = x^2 \\
$$

Thus, either $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Therefore, the solutions $(x, y)$ are: $\{ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0) \}$.